# Probability Distribution of Infinity Norm of a Vector of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, vector-spaces

Assuming $V\in \mathbb{R}^k$ to be a vector of independent random variables each with $\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ (Or even more general $\sim\mathcal{N}(a,b)$). I was wondering how I can calculate the distribution (so both $\mathbb{E}$ and $\sigma$) of infinity norm of my vector; i.e. $\|V\|_\infty=\max_{i\in \{1,2, \ldots, k\}} |V_i|$ ?

Comment: Where you have ~$\mathcal N(0,1)$ I changed it to $\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Why repost this? Anyway the general case N(a,b) will be a mess but the "standard" case N(0,1) is rather readily, but partly, solved noting that, for every nonnegative $x$, $$P(\|V\|_\infty\leqslant x)=P(|V_1|\leqslant x)^k=(2\Phi(x)-1)^k,$$ and differentiating this to get the PDF. As a consequence, $$E(\|V\|_\infty)=\int_0^\infty(1-(2\Phi(x)-1)^k)dx.$$

Comment: "Thanks. I reposted this because no one answered my previous question" This is explicitely discouraged (but perhaps you knowingly decided to go against the rules of the site simply for your convenience?).

Comment: @Did What if I have a bunch of vectors whose infinity norms are added to each other? I mean the case $P(\|V_1\|_\infty+\|V_2\|_\infty+\|V_3\|_\infty+...+\|V_N\|)_\infty<x)$?