# expected value of squared infinity norm of vector of iid gaussians

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Given a random vector

\begin{equation}
x=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)
\end{equation}

with independent and identically distributed entries $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, I would like to find a lower bound $f(n)$

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\|x\|^2_{\infty}] \geq f(n)
\end{equation}

which is reasonably tight. I know that the following equality for the non squared norm holds when $\sigma^2 =1$:

\begin{equation}
E(\|x\|_\infty)=\int_0^\infty(1-(2\Phi(x)-1)^n)dx, 
\end{equation}

where $\Phi$ is the CDF of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, see the comment to this question by @Did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456666/probability-distribution-of-infinity-norm-of-a-vector-of-independent-random-vari). Unfortunately I am not even sure on how to (tightly) lower bound the right integral for this special case.

Any help on solving the general case is much appreciated.

Comment: what is $\Phi$? the CDF of a $\mathcal N(0, 1)$? And $k$? Should it be $n$?

Comment: yes, and yes, I will add that, thank you.

Comment: By the way, the equality you give is only valid for $x_i \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$, not for $x_i \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$ as you claim. You can do some math and get an equality for $\mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)$ or restate the question.

Comment: edited thank you.

Comment: Here is the exact formula:
$$
\mathsf{E}\|X\|_{\infty}^2=2\sigma^2\int_0^{\infty}x(1-(2\Phi(x)-1)^n)\,dx.
$$

Comment: $\|x\|_\infty$ is the $n$-th order statistic of a normal random variable. This post discussing approximate order statistics for the normal distribution might be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/approximate-order-statistics-for-normal-random-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M_n:=\max_{1\le i\le n}|X_i|$. Assume w.l.o.g. that $\sigma=1$. Then, using Markov's inequality ($n\ge 2$), for any $c>0$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}M_n^2&\ge c\ln n\times\mathsf{P}(M_n\ge \sqrt{c\ln n}) \\[0.5em]
&=c\ln n\times (1-[\mathsf{P}(|X_1|<\sqrt{c\ln n})]^n).
\end{align}

Using the bound on the error function: $\operatorname{erf}(x)\le \sqrt{1-\exp(-4x^2/\pi)}$, one gets
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(|X_1|< \sqrt{c\ln n})&=\operatorname{erf}\left(\sqrt{c\ln(n)/2}\right) \\
&\le \sqrt{1-\exp(-2c\ln(n)/\pi)} \\
&=\sqrt{1-n^{-2c/\pi}}.
\end{align}

Thus, for $c\in (0,\pi/2)$,
$$
\mathsf{E}M_n^2\ge c\ln n\times\left(1-\left(1-n^{-2c/\pi}\right)^{n/2}\right)=c\ln n\times(1-o(1)).
$$